# jquery drop down onmouse over how to change it

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

[slideshare.net/tag/zendcon09?sort=views](http://www.slideshare.net/tag/zendcon09?sort=views) is based on Twitter Bootstrap and has drop down menu reacting on mouseover, on bootstrap page this plugin react on click. How to chcange it ?? I have looked in source code but havent found solution, i even put their code, and mine to diff tool and nothing.

Can someone tell me how to chcange it ?

Comment: How to change what? I can only guess at the drop down menu you are talking about. You should post your code, preferable with a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see what is currently happening

Comment: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns this is original code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it only with CSS !
Just add this code to match the menu on hover :

```
 ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu{
        display: block;    
 }
```

You can see an example here : http://jsfiddle.net/ekjxu/104/

Comment: Greate I was looking in `.js` files and it was so simple

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are just changing

```
display:none;
```

to

```
display:block;
```

on mouse over, it can be easily done with just css making something like

```
.dropdown
{
  display: none;
}

.dropdowncontainer:hover .dropdown
{
  display: block;
}
```